# Vue3 + Vite: Is there a way to let vue scoped style transform result from data-v-foo attributes to hash classname

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, postcss, vite

I know that vue.js will transform following SFC:

```html
<template>
<div class="example">123abc</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.example {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

into:

```html
<template>
<div class="example" data-v-foo>123abc</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.example[data-v-foo] {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Is there a way to let vue scoped style transform result from `data-v-foo` attributes to hash classname?

just like:

```html
<template>
<div class="f6545c">123abc</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
/* ↓ hashed classname */
.f6545c {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

I'm using latest version of Vue3 & vite. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`css-modules`](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules).

You won't have to use the `<style>` block in SFC, but instead create a `button.module.css` file that you can import in your components.

With `vite`, you can configure them like this: (see [docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#css-modules))

```js
// vite.config.js
module export {
  rollupPluginVueOptions: {
    cssModulesOptions: {
      generateScopedName: '[hash:base64:8]',
    },
  },
}
```

```html
<template>
  <button :class="[style.btn]">Styled button</button>
</template>

<script>
import style from './button.module.css'

[...]
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So can I understand that this is the function of css-module?

Comment: Yes, css-modules will convert each classes to a hash (customizable from the build options)! So this is exactly what you're looking for IMO :)